# Accessing network info in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi guys i want to access following info in my application

- The received level network strength.
- The received network  signal quality.
- network  Cell ID.
- The neighbor cells signal strength.
- Is the mobile on GSM [2G] or on the UMTS [3G].
- Mobile IMEI [international Mobile Equipment Identity].
- Call events : a dropped call, a blocked call.

is it possible to access them.i don't want to submit app on app store.it's for my person use .please suggest me some way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SystemConfiguration framework to track the signal strength. You can check this sample code for more information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It is possible. Check the UIDevice class refeence for more info